# How to deduce template argument for lambda, in function overload?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, function-templates-overloading

How should I modify my present **function signature**

```
template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc1 = Identity,typename TypeFunc2>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,TypeFunc1 calcSqrt = {},TypeFunc2 isDivisible = [](const TypeData& a,const TypeData& b) {return a%b==0;},const bool debug = false)
```

in order to be called from

```
auto fSqrt = [](decltype(n) v) {return std::sqrt(static_cast<float>(v));};
std::cout<<(isPrime(n,fSqrt)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
```

Visual Studio 2019 gives

> C2783 'bool isPrime(const TypeData &,TypeFunc1,TypeFunc2,const bool)': could not deduce template argument for 'TypeFunc2'

Everything fine without `TypeFunc2 isDivisible = [](const TypeData& a,const TypeData& b) {return a%b==0;}`, though.

What is the correct syntax for passing default lambda?
Kindly help me, please.

Comment: If one template parameter has a default argument then all parameters following it must also have default arguments.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that default arguments don't contribute to the deduction of types in template parameters.

This can be showed with this primary example:

```cpp
template <typename X>
void f(X a = 2);

int main() {
    f(); // The compiler spits out an error since it cannot determine the type 'X' holds
}
```

What you'd need to do in this scenario is to use function overloading instead:

```cpp
// ...

template<class TypeData, typename TypeFunc1, typename TypeFunc2>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,
             TypeFunc1 calcSqrt,
             TypeFunc2 isDivisible,
             const bool debug);

template<class TypeData>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n) {
    return isPrime(n, Identity{}, [](const TypeData& a, const TypeData& b) {
            return a % b == 0;
        }, false);
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruks's answer is actually very good. Another option is to use std::function, it might suit your needs as well:

```cpp
template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc1=Identity,typename TypeFunc2 = std::function<bool(const TypeData&, const TypeData&)>>
bool isPrime(
    const TypeData& n,
    TypeFunc1 calcSqrt = {},
    TypeFunc2 isDivisible = [](const TypeData& a,const TypeData& b) {return a%b==0;},
    const bool debug = false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a default type for your `TypeFunc2`, for example:

```
template<class TypeData,
         typename TypeFunc1 = Identity,
         typename TypeFunc2 = bool(*)(const TypeData&,const TypeData&)>
                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,
             TypeFunc1 calcSqrt = {},
             TypeFunc2 isDivisible = [](const TypeData& a,const TypeData& b) {return a%b==0;},
             const bool debug = false) {
  // ...
}
```